# How to export png/jpg after layout implemented

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is there any way to export a png/jpg after a layout is applied?

This works well enough for getting the initial grid layout:

```
var png64 = cy.png();
$('#downloadPNG').attr('href', png64);
```

But is there a way to get the png after a cose layout has been applied?

**EDIT**

Thanks to the below answer, found a way to do this:

```
cy.layout({
    name: 'cose',
    animateThreshold: 1,
    nodeOverlap: 100,
    gravity: 1000,
    componentSpacing: 50,
    edgeElasticity: 1000,
    minTemp: 1,
    initialTemp: 10000,
    stop: function() {
        //generate PNG image to display from "id = downloadPNG"
        var png64 = cy.png();
        $('#downloadPNG').attr('href', png64);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the layout, and get the PNG after the [`layoutstop`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#events/graph-events) event.

Comment: thanks, found the documentation in the README based on this, and put an example in the question as an edit.

Comment: Is there anyway to export after a user has selected and changed node positions? As in export "current" view.

Comment: You can call `cy.png()` pretty much any time